# You are my prefix, She is my suffix

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> You are my prefix.
>
> She is my suffix.
>
> They - my infix.
>
> I am an address.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I might be oversimplifying it, but maybe:

You are my prefix.

> 'You' - **U**

She is my suffix.

> 'She' in French is 'elle' - **L**

They - my infix.

> They **are** my infix - **R**

I am an address.

> **URL**, a web address

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> USHE

You are my prefix:

> **U**

She is my suffix:

> **SHE**, nothing tricky here

*They are* my infix:

> **U** and **SHE** are your infix

I am an address.

> Utah System of Higher Education
>  [MAP](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Utah+Higher+Education+Assistance+Authority/@40.767953,-111.9052447,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8752f51cbf487f3d:0xd007e863ba4ce706!8m2!3d40.767953!4d-111.903056)