# Rhyming Riley Riddle!

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix expresses the profound,

My suffix is found in bread,

My infix is the cosmic sound,

My whole is mourning for the dead.

Comment: In general, it's relatively better if the various "fixes" are actual English words. (If they are, this comment was a grave error, and I apologise.)

Comment: Since when was that a rule...

Comment: No rule, it's just that the wordplays that resort to abbreviations, foreign words and/or single letter clues are, because of that very property, significantly less interesting.

Comment: That is just arbitrary...

Comment: Arbitrary? You mean that in your opinion, a word that contains zero other words is exactly as interesting as a word that contains at least three?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100842/you-are-my-prefix-she-is-my-suffix

Comment: Since you seem genuinely surprised, I'll elaborate. (Other voters have their own reasons.) The main problem is you used zero effort to create the wordplay at the heart of the puzzle. It's just some random word. You then forced the cookie cutter format of the Riley riddle on that word, even though it doesn't quite fit. You then used unclear clues to hint the affix "words", so that now there are four answers, among which it would be impossible for an outside observer to pick the intended one. And you literally said "Nope try again" and "Wrong answer sorry" to those answers. That's a big no-no.

Comment: It is not uncommon for these sort of puzzles to have multiple answers.

Comment: Also what do you mean that it does not fit? What do you mean by creating a wordplay at the heart of the puzzle?

Comment: The process of creating a good Riley riddle usually starts with the tedious bit of keeping an eye out for suitable words, or even hitting the dictionary, and looking for interesting and surprising words inside other words. When you use the Riley riddle format on that kind of word, you get triple wordplay (the defining characteristic of Riley riddles), and there will pretty much never be more than one possible answer. In addition to being pretty nifty, that's also highly useful, since "no unique correct answer clearly identifiable as such" constitutes grounds for closing a question on PSE.

Comment: How do I remove this?

Comment: What does not fit is that none of the answers really "work". There is no "that's it" quality about them. None of them mean "mourning for the dead". Someone might **be** rot13(fbzoer) when mourning, but that is not what the word means. All dogs bark, but not all barking animals are dogs.

Comment: Please vote to close this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Somber

My prefix expresses the profound,

> SO

My infix is the cosmic sound,

> in the Bhagavad Gita **om** is the sound of God

My suffix is found in bread,

> **ber** are letters in bread

My whole is mourning for the dead.

> Somber, meaning grave and gloomy, is an appropriate mood for mourning.

Comment: Flip the 'e' and 'r' round to the [UK spelling](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sombre) and I think you've got the intended answer here... Also, your prefix should probably be 'SO...', which you would begin a sentence with in this context.

Comment: I thought of this after posting my near-miss answer but left it because the prefix and answer definition seemed an even bigger stretch than I had.

Comment: The first clue is so.

Comment: But yes well done!

Comment: Stiv why has this puzzle recieved so much hate.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I can't say for sure, but this might be an unfortunate combination of (i) a recent flood of 'affix-riddles' on the site over the last few months, meaning the genre might be experiencing 'fatigue' (people fed up of this type of riddle), (ii) the sense that an affix-riddle is often thrown together in a couple of minutes with seemingly little *effort* (which is a key feature of the voting system), and (iii) the remarks by Bass that it can be disappointing to find that an affix-riddle doesn't use real sub-words for its component parts - it's true that the best of the bunch do...

Comment: ...either way @Deepthinker101 I doubt that it is personal!

Comment: But how do I delete it, it looks really bad on my profile.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I think you need 10k rep to delete a question. My advice would be to forget about it, consider this a learning opportunity and move on :) Keep trying hard to create questions, and do your best to make them *interesting* (that's really key). It takes effort but it's worth it. There will still be haters - heck, most of my questions end up with at least 1 downvote (often utterly inexplicably to me, as they don't leave reasons why) - but they can be drowned out by those who love the question if you can hit that sweet spot of 'great puzzle' :) Keep trying!

Comment: Please vote to close this!!!

Comment: @Stiv It's not about the rep; if the question has an upvoted answer, the poster cannot delete it.

Comment: @Bass Ah, yes, of course! And there's two of those here as well...

Answer (score 2):

My slightly romantic answer is

> **Tomb**
>
>  The prefix is a bit of stretch:
>  **T** – the expression "to a T" means *exact*.
>  But OP is a philosphy student and may have reason to think that is *profound*.
>
>  The other parts work better. The infix is
>  **om** – the [cosmic sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) which signifies the essence of the ultimate reality.
>
>  The suffix is
>  **b** – found in **b**read, as stated in the question.
>
>  Putting them together gives
>  **T–om–b** which is a place of mourning.
>
>  One famous example is the [Taj Mahal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taj_Mahal) built in memory of Mumtaz Mahal.

Comment: You are actually pretty close one of the clues you have nailed. Another one of them, you have the right idea about how to interpret the clue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be

> Tear

My prefix expresses the profound,

> Tea - [The best kind of gossip, typically shared between friends.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tea)

My suffix is found in bread,

> Ear - A bread ear is the extra crunchy flap of crust that forms on your bread while baking.

My infix is the cosmic sound,

> E - Meaning the charge on an electron. Electromagnet waves can cause cosmic sounds.

My whole is mourning for the dead.

> Tear - One might shed tears when mourning.

Comment: Nope try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Despair

My prefix expresses the profound,

> Desp - [An abbreviation for desperate](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=desp).

My suffix is found in bread,

> Air - Bread typically has a lot of air inside.

My infix is the cosmic sound,

> Pa - The PA system.

My whole is mourning for the dead.

> Despair - When one mourns it means that one is in despair.

Comment: Wrong answer sorry.